# Add fontawesome checks to individual option tags in *ngFor after some condition checks

Tags: html, css, angular

(question completely changed)

I use `<select>` with `*ngFor` to display a list of names of properties as follows:
[image: Initial]

### Scenario

If the user interacts with the right-side panel i.e. check or un-check the values or clicks `Add property without Filters` button I save the name of the property in a JSON structure:

```
{
  selectedProperties: ['isDampProof', '..']
}
```

I want to add `<i class="fa fa-check fa-1px"></i>` in front of all the properties within the above mentioned array. Since the `option` and `i` are in a `ngFor` loop I cannot change the individual states currently. For example:

```
<select size="15" class="form-control mr-4">
    <optgroup label="Properties">
       <option *ngFor="let eachVal of dataResults"
           [selected]="searchModel.translatedProperty===eachVal.translatedProperty"
           (click)="getPropertyValues(eachVal)"
        >
<i class="fa fa-check fa-1x" *ngIf="....Condition here..."></i>
{{eachVal.translatedProperty}}
      </option>
    </optgroup>
 </select>
```

How do I add Tick marks in front of the the name which are included in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a unicode checkmark with `ngClass` since only text is allowed in the `<option>` tag.

I created a `propSelection` function which checks for if the filters for a property were selected or not.

**component.html**

```
<select size="15" class="form-control mr-4">
                            <optgroup label="Properties">
                                <option *ngFor="let eachVal of dataResults"
                                        [selected]="searchModel.translatedProperty===eachVal.translatedProperty"
                                        (click)="getPropertyValues(eachVal)"
                                        [ngClass]="{'checkMark': propSelection(eachVal.translatedProperty)}"
                                >{{eachVal.translatedProperty}}
                                </option>
</optgroup>
```

**component.ts**

```
propSelection(eachVal): boolean {
        // console.log(name);
        return this.sparqlJSON['parameters'].findIndex(i => i === eachVal) > -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to modify this snippet to work in your component but you can get the idea: `<option [disabled]="eachVal.translatedProperty === 'hasCompotion' && melanineState === false">`

And I wouldn't use the `:checked` attribute but bind a state when the checkbox is clicked so that you will now the value/state of the checkbox.

If you want you can add some more code from the component and the model of `eachVal` object to add more specific snippet.

Comment: I changed the question completely. Perhaps you can change your answer accordingly.